# How do you create a volcano plot with gene IDs?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've never created a volcano plot and I'm not quite sure if I plotted what I needed correctly. INJ is my data file, the columns of the file are GeneID, Treatment 1, Treatment 2, log2FoldChange, pvalue, padj, Gene...

I want to create a volcano plot comparing treatment 1 and treatment 2 with the gene labeled to each point.
Could someone offer some suggestions on how to do that or how to start writing code. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hi Genesis. You've really not supplied enough information to allow us to help you here. Perhaps at least an image of what you are trying to achieve, and a sample of your data (using `dput(INJ)`) would allow some suggestions on where you could start

Comment: Sorry the image didn't upload the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic setup with roughly the shape of data I expect you to have, filled with some dummy data.

These are the kinds of data you need at least, you'd need log 2 fold changes, a (FDR corrected) p-value and the IDs for the labels.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggrepel)

df <- data.frame(
  log2FoldChange = log2(rcauchy(1000, 50) / rcauchy(1000, 50)),
  padj = runif(1000),
  gene_id = paste0("ENSG00000", 1:1000)
)
#> Warning in data.frame(log2FoldChange = log2(rcauchy(1000, 50)/rcauchy(1000, :
#> NaNs produced
```

Next you typically make a decision how you'd like to display your genes. I tend to indicate wether htey are significant, and if they are significant what direction they go to.

```
df$category <- with(df, ifelse(padj > 0.05 | is.na(padj), "n.s.",
                               ifelse(log2FoldChange > 0, "Up", "Down")))
```

Also I recommend you not plot the labels of all the genes, but perhaps just the strongest effect sizes. I set the cutoff here at an absolute 1, but you should make this to be pretty with your data.

```
df$labels <- with(df, ifelse(abs(log2FoldChange) > 1 & padj < 0.05, gene_id, ""))
```

Next you just plot the log2FoldChange versus -log10 FDR corrected p-value. For labelling, I suggest you use the ggrepel package.

```
ggplot(df, aes(log2FoldChange, log10(padj))) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = category)) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = labels)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse",
                     labels = math_format()) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = expression("Log"[2]*" Fold Change"),
                     limits = function(x){c(-1, 1) * max(abs(x))})
#> Warning: Removed 13 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
#> Warning: Removed 13 rows containing missing values (geom_text_repel).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>